# Creating a forest based on recursive dependencies

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, graph-algorithm

I have a scenario Where each Item in the left of arrow is source item and right side is dependent item. Means to evaluate Source I need to first evaluate dependent items.

I want to create a map of Source to dependent items and Identify leaves for each parent. The dependencies need to be build starting from single input (`A -> B , C` ) when a dependent item doesn't depend on anything it means it is leaf. How can I build this recursively ? Any pointers will be helpful.

```
Source -> Dependencies
A -> B , C
B -> D , E , F
C -> G , H 
D->I
E-> J , K , L
F -> null
G -> null
H -> null
I -> null
J -> null
K -> null
L -> null
```

Comment: Are you asking on _how to create a specific data structure_ to model your tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traverse through the graph using BFS. Add the nodes to a new graph. Start with any. (Though this solution is not recursive, it works)

Example, your case:

Start the graph with the node A.

1. G(A)
2. G(A->B)        //now look for B's dependencies
3. G(A->B->D)     //now D's, and so on
4. G(A->B->D->I)
5. G(A->B->D->I, B->E)
6. G(A->B->D->I, B->E->J)
7. G(A->B->D->I, B->E->J, E->K, E->L)
8. G(A->B->D->I, B->E->J, E->K, E->L, B->F)
9. G(A->B->D->I, B->E->J, E->K, E->L, B->F, A->C)
10. G(A->B->D->I, B->E->J, E->K, E->L, B->F, A->C->G->H)  ---now this will be your final graph.

Now your end graph, in this case is a single graph. It may be a cluster of disconnected components. For every component now, you can do DFS which will give you the answer.

**eg.** In this graph, for (root) node `A`, all leaves will be its dependencies. For `B`, we have `(F,I,J,K and L)` etc.

Comment: Thanks , I think probably I didn't make my question clear enough. First I need to make the graph before I can search it. My input is A and from there I need to find dependencies and make the graph.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't this exactly what I've written in the answer...or I still don't get the question correct.